# Loop through controls on page - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a page in Asp.net MVC along with Javascript.

My view page and the controls on it are being dynamically generated and works great.

My only problem is I need to be able to automatically check each control for its value and compare it to the current value in the database, and I'm not sure how to do this since my controls are dynamically generated.

Is there a way to loop through all controls on the page through javascript? I would need to loop through each control, and check the value, and if need be, update the database.

Here is my portion of code where I dynamically generate each control: (generated from object in viewmodel)

```
 foreach (var row in Model.controls)
            {
                    <li>
                        <label>@row.Name</label>
                        @if (row.ControlType == "STRING" || row.ControlType == "COMMENT")
                        {
                            <input type="text" name="@row.Name" id="@row.NameID" value="@row.Value" class="form-control" style="width: 300px"/>
                        }
                        else if (row.ControlType == "DDL")
                        {
                            <select name="@row.Name" id="@row.NameID" class="form-control" style="width: 300px">
                                @foreach (var o in row.Options)
                                {
                                    <option value="@o.Value">@o.Text</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        }
                    </li>
            }
```

The ID of each control comes from the database, so I do have access to that.

I just need a way to loop through each input/dropdown and check its value.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For situations like this, I like to tag the fields I want to check with a class like:

```
<input type="text" .. class="form-control data-field" />
```

Also, you may want to tack on the original value as a data attribute like:

```
<input .. data-original-value="@row.Value" />
```

That is the value specified at rendering time.  You can loop through all the objects like so, using the following example (which I wrote only targeting inputs and would need to be expanded to handle selects).

```
$(".data-field").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var origVal = $(this).data("original-value");

    if (val != origVal) {
        //value changed
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, great response and exactly what I needed.